# temporary table with group by

Tags: sql, select, group-by, impala, temp-tables

```
with t as (
select   YEAR(start_date) as année,MONTH( start_date )as mois ,
 WEEK(start_date ) as semaine , start_date as intervalle_de_date   ,
channel as type_de_recharge,  rch_type as étoile ,
Produit ,desc_profil as forfait  ,distributeur, segment_activation_channel as canal,
offer_code as offre,tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b.segment ,tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_rch_kpi_d1.id_date
FROM tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_rch_kpi_d1

INNER JOIN tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1 ON tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_rch_kpi_d1.dn=
tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1.mdn

INNER JOIN tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b on tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1.s1= 
 tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b.s1 
and tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1.s2=  tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b.s2
where  
 (offer_code in ( 'OGSMPOSTB2B','OTPEGSMB2B','ODATAONLYB2B','ODATAB2B','OETEPOSTFMB2B','OFTEPOSTFMB2B'))
and 
(segment_activation_channel in ('VI','VD','BIR','D2D'))
)
select * from t

GROUP BY id_date;
```

wanna solve this problem

> AnalysisException: cannot combine '*' in select list with grouping or
> aggregation

Comment: Why do you want to GROUP BY id_date?

Comment: every column in a SELECT must be in the GROUP BY or have an aggregation function, so write all columns out and decide which values you want

Comment: There is no temporary table in your query?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a temporary table but a common table expression (CTE). Here is a link that explains the differences [https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/difference-between-cte-and-temp-table-and-table-variable#:~:text=Temp%20Tables%20are%20physically%20created,the%20scope%20of%20a%20statement.](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/difference-between-cte-and-temp-table-and-table-variable#:%7E:text=Temp%20Tables%20are%20physically%20created,the%20scope%20of%20a%20statement.). It might be better practice to use temporary tables because the performance is so much better than CTE's. In your case that would be:

```
--with t as (
select   YEAR(start_date) as année,MONTH( start_date )as mois ,
 WEEK(start_date ) as semaine , start_date as intervalle_de_date   ,
channel as type_de_recharge,  rch_type as étoile ,
Produit ,desc_profil as forfait  ,distributeur, segment_activation_channel as canal,
offer_code as offre,tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b.segment ,tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_rch_kpi_d1.id_date

into #t --this is the temp table
FROM tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_rch_kpi_d1

INNER JOIN tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1 ON tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_rch_kpi_d1.dn=
tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1.mdn

INNER JOIN tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b on tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1.s1= 
 tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b.s1 
and tel_test_anl_360b2b.dn_parc_b2b_d1.s2=  tel_prod_fed_ref.ref_segment_b2b.s2
where  
 (offer_code in ( 'OGSMPOSTB2B','OTPEGSMB2B','ODATAONLYB2B','ODATAB2B','OETEPOSTFMB2B','OFTEPOSTFMB2B'))
and 
(segment_activation_channel in ('VI','VD','BIR','D2D'))

select * from #t

GROUP BY id_date;

--later you can drop #t
```

now you still need to figure out on which columns you want to group by, as suggested by **nbk**,  because when using a group by, all the columns you select must be in an aggregate function (sum(), count(), avg() etc.) or the columns must be in the group by or you must leave the column out of your selection.

Comment: you should read my comment